# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil'

Tags: ios, swift, mapping, restkit

```
    var detailsMapping :RKEntityMapping = RKEntityMapping(forEntityForName:"Details", inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore)

    detailsMapping.identificationAttributes = [ "updaterId" ];

    var detailsDictionary = ["productLineDescription" : "productLineDescription","updaterId" : "updaterId","defaultProductId":"defaultProductId","activationType":"activationType","defaultCurrency":"defaultCurrency"]

    detailsMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary(detailsDictionary)

    println(detailsMapping.objectClass)
```

When i tried to check the value of  detailsMapping.objectClass  ..its printing nil . Can you anyone help me what mistake or what is alternate solution for this?

Comment: mappingsByKeyPath = {
    details = "<RKEntityMapping:0x7ff8d4c42760 objectClass=(null) propertyMappings=(\n    \"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x7ff8d482a1a0 defaultCurrency => defaultCurrency>\",\n    \"<RKAttributeMapping:

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `RKEntityMapping` you are using an `entity` to create instances, not `objectClass`, so it generally isn't very useful to query it. That said, it must exist or you would get an exception when you call `mappingForEntityForName:inManagedObjectStore:`.

This shouldn't really be the cause of an issue as you shouldn't be directly using the `objectClass`.